# DataGridView right click event and pass-through of parameters to sub

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I read a lot of things here in the forum, but I can't find a solution for my problem.

I have a `DataGridView` with a `ContextMenu`.

My aim is to call a function from the context menu and pass through parameters e.g. linenumber of selected dgv row.

Here is my code, that contains a `ContextMenu`, but how I could pass-through some parameters to a function?

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As DataGridView, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim m As New ContextMenu

        m.MenuItems.Add(New MenuItem("Sub1"))
        m.MenuItems.Add(New MenuItem("Sub2"))

        Dim currentMouseOverRow As Integer = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex

        m.Show(DataGridView1, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Now I have got a solution that works, but I think it is not the best solution and I can do a lot of improvement.

Maybe it would be possible to code custom events, that can pass through some datas of the gridview. I hope somebody is interested to give some input to improve the following (working) code to look something like professional.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public gpath As String = "D:\kvt.txt"
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim file = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("d:\kvt.txt")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        For Each line As String In file
            dt.Rows.Add(line)
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dataGridView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As DataGridView, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
        Dim cMenu As New ContextMenuStrip
        Dim MenuItemClone As New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
        MenuItemClone.Text = "Clone"
        cMenu.Items.Add(MenuItemClone)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim currentMouseOverRow As Integer = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
            cMenu.Show(DataGridView1, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
            AddHandler MenuItemClone.Click, AddressOf CloneRepo
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloneRepo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim SelectedName As String = DataGridView1("Name", DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).FormattedValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't use a `ContextMenu`. That's been outdated since 2005.  Use a `ContextMenuStrip`. Generally speaking, you should be creating the menu in the designer and assigning it to the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the grid.

Comment: The informations of the clicked line of the datagridview should be passed through in Sub CloneRepo. Here I work with my global datagridview. Thats not professional I think.

Comment: No it shouldn't. In your code, `CloneRepo` is an event handler. You don't call an event handler so you can't pass it anything. You need to go and get the data you need from inside that event handler, which means that you need to put it somewhere to get it from first. You already know why what you want doesn't work so stop trying make it magically happen. You've been shown how to achieve your end goal, i.e. access the clicked row in the menu item's `Click` event handler. Stop messing about and just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can right-click on a cell in a `DataGridView` and then perform an action relative to that cell when you click a menu item:

```
Private lastClickedCell As DataGridViewCell

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 AndAlso
       e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        lastClickedCell = DataGridView1.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right AndAlso
       DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell Then
        'Display the menu when right-clicking on a cell.
        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(DataGridView1, e.Location)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClearToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Clear the cell that was right-clicked.
    lastClickedCell.Value = Nothing
End Sub
```

The `ContextMenuStrip` was created in the designer for this example. I would recommend doing that in your case too, even if you need to choose items dynamically.  You can clear the menu and add and/or remove items in the `CellMouseClick` or `MouseClick` event handlers of the grid, or the `Opening` event handler of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
        Dim col As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim m As New ContextMenuStrip
            col.TextBox.ContextMenuStrip = m

            Dim tsp As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub1", Nothing, New EventHandler(AddressOf TestMessage))

            Dim tsp1 As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub2", Nothing, New EventHandler(AddressOf TestMessage))

            m.Name = "Menulist"
            m.Items.Add(tsp)
            m.Items.Add(tsp1)
            Dim currentMouseOverRow As Integer = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
            m.Show(DataGridView1, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TestMessage()
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked")
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is no solution for me. I have already a context menu. The problem is to pass parameters like row index into a other function or sub.

Answer (score 0):

try this and use 'Tag':

```
    Dim currentMouseOverRow As Integer

Structure MyStructure
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick
    Dim Mystruct As MyStructure
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        Dim m As New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip
        Dim MymenuToolStripMenuItem1 As New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
        MymenuToolStripMenuItem1.Text = "menu1"
        AddHandler MymenuToolStripMenuItem1.Click, AddressOf MymenuToolStripMenuItem1_Click
        m.Items.Add(MymenuToolStripMenuItem1)
        Dim MymenuToolStripMenuItem2 As New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
        MymenuToolStripMenuItem2.Text = "menu2"
        AddHandler MymenuToolStripMenuItem2.Click, AddressOf MymenuToolStripMenuItem2_Click
        m.Items.Add(MymenuToolStripMenuItem2)
        Mystruct.x = e.X
        Mystruct.x = e.X
        MymenuToolStripMenuItem2.Tag = Mystruct
        currentMouseOverRow = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex

        m.Show(DataGridView1, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MymenuToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("click Menu1:" & currentMouseOverRow)
End Sub

Private Sub MymenuToolStripMenuItem2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Mystruct As MyStructure
    Mystruct = CType(CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem).Tag, MyStructure)
    MessageBox.Show("click Menu2:" & currentMouseOverRow & " x:" & Mystruct.x & " y:" & Mystruct.y)
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution would be good for me, but the problem is, that the event handler excepts only "ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs" as signature. This means that I have no possibility to pass through the clicked line number of my datagridview to the Sub "MymenuToolStripMenuItem1_Click" because the sender is the menuitem. And exactly this is my problem.

Comment: True, there is a problem to solve, you need to use a public variable or use the control tag to send it. Revisit the code again for example